# How to set height to child tag

Tags: html, reactjs, height

I want to set the height of a child tag to 100% but as soon as I redirect to another page the height remains same disabling the page to scroll.

Image 1.css

```
body{
  background: url("Resources/Cash.jpeg");
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#root{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.account{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

This style without setting the `height` makes the first page look half but the second page which is 'Create' looks perfect and scrollable.

Image 1

[image: Image 2]

Image 2.css

```
body{
  background: url("Resources/Cash.jpeg");
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#root{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.account{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

But after adding `height` to `html`,`body`,`account` and  `root`, the home page looks perfect but the 'Create' page has 'Height' of 100% so it fits the page and becomes unable to scroll.

Image 2

[image: Image 1]

React Html Outer body

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="account">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way so the final output Home looks like image 2 and the Create page looks like image 1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are setting the height exactly, but if you are using the same container for both pages, then I can think of two solutions out of the box:

1. Give the `height` CSS property to the component that is displaying the content, not the parent container that is wrapping it.
2. Use `className`, and change them dynamically. This can be done with the help of `React.useState` hook. Set the `className` to be one thing when it is on the first page and change it when you move to the second page. And Match those classNames in your CSS files.

Comment: I've tried changing the height of different elements but its the problem with the parent element is #root which is applied to all pages so changing it would make other pages look different, can you please give some information along with code @Zaid Shawahin